# Как сделать запрос параллельно через ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

К примеру, есть инпут, я ввожу cat, dog и в качестве запроса должно отправиться не "htpp://api&q=cat, dog", а по отдельности сначала "htpp://api&q=cat", а затем "htpp://api&q=dog"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем собвственно вопрос?

```
let [resCat,resDog] = await Promise.all([
      fetch('htpp://api&q=cat'),
      fetch('htpp://api&q=dog')
])
```

Запросы запустятся параллельно, второй не будет ожидать первый.
[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) для ожидания результатов обоих запросов.

Если запускаете из не-асинхронной функции, то используйте вместо `await` `.then()`.

```
 let urlList = 'cat, dog,cow ,parrot'.split(/\s*\,\s*/)
   .map(query => 'http://google.com?q='+query);
 Promise.all(urlList.map(url => Axios.get(url)))
   .then(([res1,res2,res3])=>{
     /* обработка результата */
  })
  .catch(err => {
     /* обработка ошибки */
  });
```

В массиве может быть сколько угодно url, массив может быть сформирован заранее.

Comment: У меня это делается в контексте, получется
            const response = await Axios.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=${API_KEY}&tag=${tag}`)
            dispatch(fetchImages(response.data.data))
И в этот тэг подставляется значение инпута. Я правильно понимаю, что тут тоже нужно в Promise.all это обернуть, а в зависимости добавить сам респонс?

Comment: Promise.all()  использовать не обязательно, он выполняет второстепенную функцию. Попробую объяснить, сек.

Comment: Суть то в том, что я ввожу неопределенное количество значений и они должны последовательно через запятую быть подставлены в запрос, т.е в тот тэг из юрла, с этим проблемы

Comment: А вы имеете в виду вы вводите `"cat, dog"`и хотите получить `"htpp://api&q=cat"`, и `"htpp://api&q=dog"`

Comment: Да, тот же диспатч, получается, должен обработать уже 2 раза, ну и там в зависимости от количества значений

Comment: Я вас понял, сейчас напишу код в ответе для наглядности

Comment: Вы меня не совсем поняли, конкретно с запросом всё ясно, меня интересует именно то, как именно разделить сами запросы с помощью запятой. Вы показываете, как можно запустить запросы для разных урлов, но мой вопрос заключается в том, как из значения из инпута разделить запятой и каждое значение отправлялось в диспатч, запуская их по очереди

Comment: Я немного изменил ответ. Строку можно разделить методом `.split()`. Затем массив запросов можно переделать в массив URL методом `.map()`.